# Роутер, через кабель не открывается часть сайтов, через wi-fi всё нормально

Tags: роутер, wifi

Роутер *ZyXel Viva*. Через *wi-fi* всё работает хорошо.

Если тот же ноутбук подключить через кабель, то перестаёт открываться часть сайтов.

Comment: Скорее всего, что-то не так.

Comment: Это я к чему: без подробного описания настроек, без описания какие именно сайты не открываются, без описания какая ошибка возвращается - конкретнее ответ и не дашь. Может, даже логи есть на роутере.

Comment: в ноутбуке сравните [mtu](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) на соответствующих сетевых интерфейсах в обоих вариантах подключения. если значения будут разные и на ethernet-интерфейсе больше, чем на wifi, попробуйте уменьшить mtu до «вайфайного».

Comment: Завтра отпишу по сайтам, и посмотрю насчёт логов.
C mtu побывал играться но ничего, не поменялось. 
Самое интересное что вчера всё работало хорошо, а на утро (собственно ничего не кто не менял), начались приколы.

Comment: @Hatsu, не забудьте завтра упомянуть `@имя-пользователя`, к которому обратитесь, чтобы он получил уведомление. в дискуссии уже двое отметились, так что безадресный ответ, насколько я понимаю, не пошлёт оповещения ни мне, ни *Regent*-у.

Comment: @Regent Проблема оказалась не в роутере, а в ноутбуке.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin mtu одинаковый, уменьшение mtu не дало ни каких результатов

Comment: @Hatsu то есть вы разобрались в чём была проблема? Если "да", и ответ может быть полезен для других людей, то можете разместить объяснение в качестве ответа. Если решение полезно только для вас, то тогда имеет смысл удалить вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, получить уведомление на безадресное сообщение от автора можно только в том случае, если вы единственный, кто отписался.

Comment: @Regent проблема решается, но как мне кажется решить её в разумные сроки  не получится. К тому же проблема уже не соответствует заданной теме и тегам, так что лучше будет удалить вопрос. Спасибо за активную помощь.

Comment: @Hatsu за пассивную помощь, я бы сказал :) На здоровье.